Reference about cancellation property for semigroups
Have the semigroups with the following cancellation property been studied?
Property: Let $S$ be a semigroup and $x,y\in S$ such that $xz=yz,$ for all $z\in S,$ then $x=y$.

Obvious remark: for monoids this is trivial (taking $z=1$).

Other obvious remark: if one writes $R_z(x)=xz$, this is the requirement of injectivity of $z\mapsto R_z$. And obvious example where it fails: set with an element $0$ and not reduced to ${0}$, with constant law $xy=0$ $\forall x,y$.

This seems to be called a right reductive semigroup, at least on Wikipedia and nLab.

@NaïmFavier Thanks, that is exactly what i was looking for.

A semigroup with this property seems to be called a right reductive semigroup (Wikipedia, nLab).
